# .NET Core SDKs are not detected when creating an ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having trouble with Visual Studio 2019 not finding the .NET Core SDKs.

I have installed a preview version of .NET Core 3.0 (v.9) and removed all the previous version of .NET Core SDKs.

When I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core Web Application from the template form in VS2019, I am getting the following error below:

No .NET Core SDKs were detected, ensure they are included in the environment variable 'PATH'. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cStBA.png

I have checked on my environment variables and the paths to the dotnet core folders are available. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iX2r.png

Also, I have the  Use previews of the .NET Core SDKs in the Tools->Options->Environment->Preview Features, selected.

Has anyone else got any ideas where I can take it from as I have followed Microsoft help guide on this issue but to no avail?

Comment: You need the preview version of Visual Studio 2019 to use .NET Core 3.0.

Comment: I had similar issues but was not able to find a proper solution. In the end I had to create a .net core 2 application, and update the project files manually to use .net core 3.

Comment: You need to restart your pc, to can create v3 projects

Comment: You should definitely use VS 2019 __preview__. Side by side installing with released version works without problem. There is a switch in the released version of VS that allows to use preview .net core. But it is not supported and not recommended to use. Also it is often a good idea to remove the _bin_ and _lib_ folders

Comment: Thanks, guys I am using the VS2019 Enterprise. I will try the preview version and see how it goes.